# Merging of 2 Data tables (Includes Empty Rows) using LINQ C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datatable

I am trying to join 2 data table using LINQ C#, one table has some empty values say example,

Data table 1 Master

[image]

Data table 2 Sample

[image]

Result what I am expecting by joining this 2 table is,

Result table

[image]

so far what I have tried is

```
 var result = from Sam_Rep in Sample.AsEnumerable()
    join Mas_Rep in master.AsEnumerable()
                     on Sam_Rep.Field<string>("ID No") equals Mas_Rep.Field<string>("SL No")
                 select new
                     {
                         SAPID = Sam_Rep.Field<string>("ID No"),
                         Desg  = Mas_Rep.Field<string> ("Designation")
          };
```

But the result I am getting by using above code is,

[image]

Let me know any one can help me on this

Comment: Please don't use images to show data. Please rollback your edit to show mine, or wrap your original in code formatting.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement left outer joins, You can use LINQ to perform a left outer join by calling the DefaultIfEmpty method on the results of a group join.

For example:

```cs
class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

class Pet
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Person Owner { get; set; }
}

public static void LeftOuterJoinExample()
{
    Person magnus = new Person { FirstName = "Magnus", LastName = "Hedlund" };
    Person terry = new Person { FirstName = "Terry", LastName = "Adams" };
    Person charlotte = new Person { FirstName = "Charlotte", LastName = "Weiss" };
    Person arlene = new Person { FirstName = "Arlene", LastName = "Huff" };

    Pet barley = new Pet { Name = "Barley", Owner = terry };
    Pet boots = new Pet { Name = "Boots", Owner = terry };
    Pet whiskers = new Pet { Name = "Whiskers", Owner = charlotte };
    Pet bluemoon = new Pet { Name = "Blue Moon", Owner = terry };
    Pet daisy = new Pet { Name = "Daisy", Owner = magnus };

    // Create two lists.
    List<Person> people = new List<Person> { magnus, terry, charlotte, arlene };
    List<Pet> pets = new List<Pet> { barley, boots, whiskers, bluemoon, daisy };

    var query = from person in people
                join pet in pets on person equals pet.Owner into gj
                from subpet in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
                select new { person.FirstName, PetName = subpet?.Name ?? String.Empty };

    foreach (var v in query)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{v.FirstName+":",-15}{v.PetName}");
    }
}

// This code produces the following output:
//
// Magnus:        Daisy
// Terry:         Barley
// Terry:         Boots
// Terry:         Blue Moon
// Charlotte:     Whiskers
// Arlene:
```

for more information please read this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-left-outer-joins)

Comment: Thanks for providing the code snippet. But I don't have an option to change the data table to list. I want to do it using datable along with LINQ. Similar the code what I have used

Comment: Same, also you can try to change it to list by using .ToList()

Comment: Is there any way to do it using 2 datatables instead of doing List??